# XSL won't write xmlns:xsl?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

How do I write the XSL namespace in my output?

I'm using XSL to analyze an XSL document and report problems it finds, including copying the node. The problem is that I can't get `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` written into the output's root node, which means it gets repeated every time I copy an `xsl:*` element.

This doesn't seem to happen with other namespaces. For example, take the following XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:custom="custom uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2 uri" exclude-result-prefixes="" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <custom:element xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:element name="custom2:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="custom2:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever2</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </custom:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run against any XML document, I get what I expect except that `xmlns:xsl` is missing from `custom:element` even though I specify it and `exclude-result-prefixes` is explicitly blank... but that's fine, it's not used in the output.

```
<custom:element xmlns:custom="custom uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2 uri">
    <custom2:function name="whatever"/>
    <custom2:function name="whatever2"/>
</custom:element>
```

**However**, if I replace both `name="custom2:function"` with `name="xsl:function"` like so...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:custom="custom uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2 uri" exclude-result-prefixes="" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <custom:element xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
            <xsl:element name="xsl:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever2</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </custom:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then `xmlns:xsl` is *still* missing from `custom:element` and I get

```
<custom:element xmlns:custom="custom uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2 uri">
    <xsl:function xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="whatever"/>
    <xsl:function xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="whatever2"/>
</custom:element>
```

instead of what I want:

```
<custom:element  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:custom="custom uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2 uri">
    <xsl:function name="whatever"/>
    <xsl:function name="whatever2"/>
</custom:element>
```

How do I change my stylesheet to declare `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` I the root node?

Comment: See if this helps: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#namespace-aliasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Saxon a namespace alias helps:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:custom="custom-uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2-uri" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl" xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <custom:element xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias">
            <xsl:element name="xsl:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever2</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </custom:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiX outputs

```
<custom:element xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:custom="custom-uri"
                xmlns:custom2="custom2-uri">
   <xsl:function name="whatever"/>
   <xsl:function name="whatever2"/>
</custom:element>
```

Most times you would just put the namespace declaration on the root element with e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:custom="custom-uri" xmlns:custom2="custom2-uri" version="3.0"
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl" />
    <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
        <custom:element>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:function">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">whatever2</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </custom:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I was not sure whether you want to restrict it to a certain element so the first sample declares it on that element and then of course additionally on the `xsl:namespace-alias` so that it makes sense.

Comment: Note that you can use the namespace-alias on literal element constructors. No need for `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` (unless you just really like typing a lot). I would use: `<axsl:function name="whatever"/>` and `<axsl:function name="whatever2"/>`